# Question regarding a proof in a paper

Tags: proof-explanation, normed-spaces, spheres

[image]

After $(11)$, $e^{-s}$ disappear. To me, you can only remove that term and the inequality still stays valid, if after removing, it makes the LHS smaller. However, it is not obvious to me that such guarantee exists for this proof.

Am I missing anything? Or is this proof wrong?

This proof is from the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09414.

Comment: Do you understand line 12?

Comment: @Servaes Yes. Why? The author just multiply LHS by (C-1)/(C-1) and then apply Jensen inequality. But the exponential term is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging (13) into (12) yields that
$$\frac{1}{C(C-1)}\sum_{i,j,i\neq j}e^{s(W_i^TW_j)}\geq e^{-\frac{s}{C-1}}.$$
Plugging this into (11) yields that
$$\frac{1}{P_W}\geq 1+\frac{e^{-s}}{C}\sum_{i,j,i\neq j}e^{s(W_i^TW_j)}
\geq 1+(C-1)e^{-s}e^{-\frac{s}{C-1}}=1+(C-1)e^{-\frac{sC}{C-1}},$$
which is precisely what (14) says.